# Саша - Шура

Tags: имена-собственные

Читал вопрос о том, как Ричард стал Диком, и в одном из ответов прозвучала фраза: "Как Александр стал Шурой, все знают". Честно говоря, я не знаю. И мне было бы очень интересно узнать, как Александр и Александра могли превратиться в Шуру. Саша - это более-менее понятно, но почему Шура?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: А где про Дика было? Мне интересно сопоставить с недавней дискуссией на "лингве".

Comment: Хороший вопрос! +1 
И мне тоже это как-то непонятно. Александр -- и вдруг Шура...

А Ксения может быть Шурой? Называли так одну бабушку, ныне покойную.

Comment: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/41086/%D1

Answer (score 3):

> Александр-Алексаша-Саша-Сашура-Шура

Да. Это еще ничего. У меня двоюродная бабка из Александры стала Шарлоттой.

> А Ксения может быть Шурой? Называли так одну бабушку, ныне покойную.

Может быть всё. Ник-неймы в документах не пишут. Сейменые традиции еще и не то делают. 
А касательно Ксении...  Я думаю, здесь тот же ряд: Ксения-Ксюра-Сюра-Шура

посмотрите, какой объемный список вариантов дает Ксения:
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/personal_names/18122/%D0%9A%D1%81%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Спасибо!

.

> У меня двоюродная бабка из Александры стала Шарлоттой. 

Интересно! Я обратные примеры знаю. К примеру, на Украине народ попроще может всякие слишком пафосные и необычные имена переделывать на более простые. Например, даже такое не слишком сложное в произношении имя, как Анна. 

Анна -- Ганна -- (неожиданно!) баба Галя :-) (но это редкий случай)
Кристина -- ХрыстЫна - ХрЫстя.

.

> Сейменые традиции еще и не то делают.

Это точно. Знаю Алексея, который из Лёши стал Лёней. Хотя Лёня - это уменьшительное от Леонид.

Answer (score 2):

Александр – Алексаша – Саша – Сашура – Шура.